# How to install Pygame on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, pygame

How can I install Pygame on Windows 7 (64 bit)? I've tried everything I can think of but nothing works.

I am running CPython 2.7.3 32bit.

Installing via `pip install pygame` from `cmd` failed with the error (yes I have MinGW installed)

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "c:\users\r\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-R\pygame\setup.py", line 325, in
 run

    "mingw32: required environment variable"

RuntimeError: mingw32: required environment variable MINGW_ROOT_DIRECTORY not se
t

----------------------------------------
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\r\\app
data\\local\\temp\\pip-build-R\\pygame\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).re
ad().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\r\appd
ata\local\temp\pip-vi1djm-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\r\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-R\py
game
```

After setting `MINGW_ROOT_DIRECTORY=C:\MinGW` and trying again I got the error

```
Downloading/unpacking pygame
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pygame
    WARNING, DLL for smpeg library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for tiff library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for SDL_ttf library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for SDL_image library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for vorbisfile library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for jpeg library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for vorbis library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for SDL_mixer library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for png library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for SDL library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for ogg library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for z library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for portmidi library not found.

    warning: no files found matching 'readme.txt'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*\CVS'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*\*\CVS'
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame
    WARNING, DLL for smpeg library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for tiff library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for SDL_ttf library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for SDL_image library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for vorbisfile library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for jpeg library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for vorbis library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for SDL_mixer library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for png library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for SDL library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for ogg library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for z library not found.
    WARNING, DLL for portmidi library not found.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\r\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-R\pygame\setup.py", line 491
, in <module>
        setup(**PACKAGEDATA)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.38-py2.7.egg\setuptools
\command\install.py", line 53, in run
        return _install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\r\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-R\pygame\setup.py", line 352
, in run
        sys.version_info[:2])
    RuntimeError: The dependencies are linked to the wrong C runtime for Python
2.7
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__
file__='c:\\users\\r\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-R\\pygame\\setup.py';exec(
compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install
 --record c:\users\r\appdata\local\temp\pip-xe1cpi-record\install-record.txt --s
ingle-version-externally-managed:
    WARNING, DLL for smpeg library not found.

WARNING, DLL for tiff library not found.

WARNING, DLL for SDL_ttf library not found.

WARNING, DLL for SDL_image library not found.

WARNING, DLL for vorbisfile library not found.

WARNING, DLL for jpeg library not found.

WARNING, DLL for vorbis library not found.

WARNING, DLL for SDL_mixer library not found.

WARNING, DLL for png library not found.

WARNING, DLL for SDL library not found.

WARNING, DLL for ogg library not found.

WARNING, DLL for z library not found.

WARNING, DLL for portmidi library not found.

running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\r\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-R\pygame\setup.py", line 491, in
 <module>

    setup(**PACKAGEDATA)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.38-py2.7.egg\setuptools\com
mand\install.py", line 53, in run

    return _install.run(self)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "c:\users\r\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-R\pygame\setup.py", line 352, in
 run

    sys.version_info[:2])

RuntimeError: The dependencies are linked to the wrong C runtime for Python 2.7

----------------------------------------
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\r\\app
data\\local\\temp\\pip-build-R\\pygame\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).re
ad().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\r\appd
ata\local\temp\pip-xe1cpi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\r\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-R\py
game
Storing complete log in C:\Users\R\pip\pip.log
```

The binary installers do not work either. When I try to run the installer, the menu says "Python from another location - Entire feature will be unavailable". If I proceed anyway, the installation completes successfully, but trying to import Pygame still says no such module. I'm not sure if it failed to install or if it actually did install but didn't update the paths correct, or what, but either way it doesn't work.

What can I do? I'm at my wits end.

Comment: How did you install Python?  Did you use the installer from python.org?  What binary installer for pygame are you trying?

Comment: @Bren Yes, I used the installer from python.org. The pygame installer I used were the win32-py2.7 msis from http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml (I tried both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a completely different problem in installing some other library(it was probably PyTables), some months back. I found a great (but unofficial) resource for Windows binaries for Python libraries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). I was able to install quite a few of these binaries without an issue.

If you are looking to solve the issue, I recommend going into the source of setup.py(line 345):

```
def run(self):
        """Extended to set MINGW_ROOT_DIRECTORY, PATH and LIBRARY_PATH"""

        if self.compiler in mingw32_compilers:
            # Add MinGW environment variables.
            if 'MINGW_ROOT_DIRECTORY' not in os.environ:
                # Use MinGW setup conifiguration file if present.
                import mingwcfg
                try:
                    mingw_root = mingwcfg.read()
                except IOError:
                    raise RuntimeError(
                        "mingw32: required environment variable"
                        " MINGW_ROOT_DIRECTORY not set")
                os.environ['MINGW_ROOT_DIRECTORY'] = mingw_root
                path = os.environ['PATH']
                os.environ['PATH'] = ';'.join([os.path.join(mingw_root, 'bin'),
                                               path])
            if sys.version_info >= (2, 6):
                # The Visual Studio 2008 C library is msvcr90.dll.
                c_runtime_path = os.path.join(self.__sdl_lib_dir, 'msvcr90')
            elif sys.version_info >= (2, 4):
                # The Visual Studio 2003 C library is msvcr71.dll.
                c_runtime_path = os.path.join(self.__sdl_lib_dir, 'msvcr71')
            else:
                # The Visual Studio 6.0 C library is msvcrt.dll,
                # the MinGW default.
                c_runtime_path = ''
            if c_runtime_path and os.path.isdir(c_runtime_path):
                # Override the default msvcrt.dll linkage.
                os.environ['LIBRARY_PATH'] = c_runtime_path
            elif not (c_runtime_path or
                      glob.glob(os.path.join(self.__sdl_lib_dir,
                                             'msvcr*'))):
                pass
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("The dependencies are linked to"
                                   " the wrong C runtime for"
                                   " Python %i.%i" %
                                   sys.version_info[:2]
```

On a preliminary look, the problem seems as though you do not have the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime, which you can download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5555). Hope this helps.

Comment: When I tried to install the MSVC++ Runtime, it said I already had a newer version installed.

Comment: I ended up using the unofficial installer. It's a shame the official installers don't seem to work.

Comment: Getting some libraries installed in python in windows is a major pain, even with pip and easy_install. I had to spend nearly 3 days trying to install PyMC before resorting to the above link. Still, please do reach out to the PyGame community with the problems you are facing, as well. The unofficial binaries are great, but it would be better (for the community) if any potential problem in the installer is resolved in the official release too.

Answer (score 0):

If you get trouble when install pygame error about missing visual studio 10+. I have the answer: The problem is not about have or not have visual studio, because I try many version but it not work. The problem is file: between tar.gz and .whl so, this is the solution:

1. **Download file:**

   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame
   Go here and download your pygame version, notice about x64 or x86 and python version. My system is x64 and python is 3.4 so I choose: pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
2. **Put it in some where to install:**

   I put it in "C:", so open cmd and type:

   ```
   cd C:\
   ```

   (this is change location to C:)
3. **Install**

   ```
   pip install C:\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
   ```

Done!